# select all from a specific record

Tags: sql

The table:

```
autn  itcode  date  qty  phstock    
----------------------------------------
1     10      1/1   1   
2     5       2/2   1   
3     6       1/1   5
4     10      2/1   5
5     9       1/1   5   
6     10      3/1   1    5
7     5       5/1   2
8     5       6/1   5   
9     10      5/5   1   
10    5       7/1   2   
11    10      7/2   5    2
12    10      7/8   2
```

How to get the output as bellow:

```
autn  itcode  date  qty  phstock
--------------------------------
11    10      7/2   5    2
12    10      7/8   2
```

Hint: I want only record from I last entered in the feiled 'phstock'![enter image description here][1]

Comment: what rdbms you are using?

Comment: Rolled back to the nicely formatted one... why is this community wiki btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
  from YourTable x 
 where x.date = (
   select max(y.date) from Yourtable y
   )
```

If I get you right, you want it for a specific 'phstock' only.

```
select * from YourTable c
 where x.date = (
   select max(y.date) from Yourtable y where y.phstock = <YourPhStockHere>
   )
 and x.phstock = <YourPhStockHere>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would return all rows after the latest row for which `phstock` is set:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   date >=
        (
        select  max(date)
        from    YourTable
        where   phstock is not null
        )
```